# How to solve the "Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat" problem

Tags: javascript

I want to replace every occurence of a question mark, point, comma etc. in a string called TextToSimplify but I keep getting the error as said in the title. What can I do about it

```
ToSimplifyText = ToSimplifyText.replace(/,/g, "");
ToSimplifyText = ToSimplifyText.replace(/./g, "");
ToSimplifyText = ToSimplifyText.replace(/!/g, "");
ToSimplifyText = ToSimplifyText.replace(/?/g, "");
ToSimplifyText = ToSimplifyText.replace(/'/g, "");
```

Comment: Use one regex with a character class: `ToSimplifyText = ToSimplifyText.replace(/[,.!?']/g, "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all that stuff on one single replace, like this:

```js
ToSimplifyText = "Hello. Dude! Aren't you ok?"
console.log(ToSimplifyText.replace(/[,.'?!]/g, ""));
```

Note, that if you want to replace a special character, you will have to escape it with `\`. Note also, this is not necessary when using a [set of characters](https://javascript.info/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges) with `[...]`, like in the previous example:

```js
ToSimplifyText = "Hello. Dude! Aren't you ok?"
console.log(ToSimplifyText.replace(/\?/g, ""));
```